# Magento Homepage Featured products blurry

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a featured products section on my magento homepage and they are quite blurry compared to the product page image which is exactly the same image. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've attached the image from the homepage and the image from the product page:

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's using the same image? Featured products may be using a thumbnail but resizing it larger so this it goes blurry. If the same image is resized, it shouldn't look that bad.

Comment: Have you got installed some image optimiser? This could cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recall running into this issue and it being a result of Magento's wrapper to the image manipulation library.  I remember spending a significant amount trying to figure this out and that it only happened for certain image types.

This link looks like it contains the resolution to the problem I encountered quite a while back when this problem was real.
http://www.webr2.com/magento-resize-image-quality/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the browser is trying to resize the image according to specified css elements such as width and height.

If it's not trying to increase the size of the image based on a thumbnail version, it might be that it's specifying a different ratio to the original image, even a pixel or two difference in width or height can cause this kind of blurring.